# Accessing request.body and request.FILES from mailgun forwarding route

Tags: python, django, mailgun

My goal is to read the contents of a forwarded mail with an attachment using mailgun's route. When the email doesnt include an attachment, i can freely grab other attributes like the sender,subject and text but when i try to access `request.FILES` i get error saying `You cannot access body after reading from request's data stream` even though i have added `@csrf_exempt` decorator to my view function

```
data =urllib.parse.parse_qs(raw_request_body.decode())
subject = data['subject']
sender = data['sender']
date = data['Date']
text = data['stripped-text']
```

but when i try to even get `request.FILES` after this block of code, it throws an error

Comment: Why would you think crsf_exempt had anything to do with this? And why are you accessing the request body directly? Show the rest of the code.

Comment: Show us your full view, is this a view that receives a POST request from mailgun? You should just use `request.POST` and `request.FILES` as you would normally do. No need to use `urllib` or any of that.